# Issue creating a popup

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a popup within my app; however, when the button is pressed, the popup doesn't appear. There isn't an error and the app doesn't crash. The code being used is slightly modified from some previous code I used for a popup, which works.

```
        ISOButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                inflater2 = (LayoutInflater)
                getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                popupView = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.isochanger, null);
                final PopupWindow popupwindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);
                popupwindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        popupwindow.dismiss();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

The full activity is:

```
package com.example.startrailscamera;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.widget.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   TextureView textureView;
   ImageButton imageButton, singleImageButton;
   TextView ISOText;
   SeekBar seekBar;
   Integer maxISO, minISO, progress, ISO, width, height, ISO2, ISO3, ISO4, ISORange, ISO5;
   Range<Integer> rangeISO;
   String cameraId;
   Button ISOButton, isomin, iso2, iso3, iso4, iso5, isomax;
   boolean focusable;
   View popupView;
   LayoutInflater inflater, inflater2;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       imageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
       imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                       getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cameralayout, null);
               width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
               height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
               focusable = true;
               final PopupWindow popupwindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

               popupwindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

               popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                       popupwindow.dismiss();
                       return true;
                   }
               });

           }

       });
       CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

       if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           return;
       }
       try {
           CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
           maxISO = rangeISO.getUpper();
           minISO = rangeISO.getLower();
           rangeISO = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE);
           Range<Long> exposureTimeRange = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_EXPOSURE_TIME_RANGE);
       } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       ISORange = maxISO - minISO;
       ISO2 = minISO + (ISORange/5);
       ISO3 = minISO + (ISORange/5*2);
       ISO4 = minISO + (ISORange/5*3);
       ISO5 = minISO + (ISORange/5*4);
       isomin.setText(minISO);
       iso2.setText(ISO2);
       iso3.setText(ISO3);
       iso4.setText(ISO4);
       iso5.setText(ISO5);
       isomax.setText(maxISO);

       ISOButton = findViewById(R.id.ISOButton);
       ISOButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               inflater2 = (LayoutInflater)
               getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               popupView = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.isochanger, null);
               final PopupWindow popupwindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);
               popupwindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
               popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                       popupwindow.dismiss();
                       return true;
                   }
               });

           }
       });

       }

   }
```

and the XML file that I'm trying to show is

````
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/iso3"
       android:layout_width="58dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
       android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iso4"
       android:text="3" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/isomin"
       android:layout_width="58dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
       android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iso2"
       android:text="1" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/iso4"
       android:layout_width="58dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
       android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iso5"
       android:text="4" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/iso5"
       android:layout_width="58dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
       android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/isomax"
       android:text="5" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/isomax"
       android:layout_width="58dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
       android:text="6" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/iso2"
       android:layout_width="58dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
       android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iso3"
       android:text="2" />
</RelativeLayout> ```
````

Comment: I tried your code its working, make sure your ISOButton onClick event is working, and your R.layout.isochanger file has some contents, or different background color from view. I can help you batter if you can update me with your full activity class code and R.layout.isochanger xml file.

Comment: @Afsaredrisy I've added the full activity to the post. I much appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was with `width` and `height`.

I commented unnecessary code for this specific problem.
Here is your working activity code

```java
package com.andruid.magic.imagesegmentationlib;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.widget.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextureView textureView;
    ImageButton imageButton, singleImageButton;
    TextView ISOText;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    Integer maxISO, minISO, progress, ISO, width, height, ISO2, ISO3, ISO4, ISORange, ISO5;
    Range<Integer> rangeISO;
    String cameraId="0";
    Button ISOButton, isomin, iso2, iso3, iso4, iso5, isomax;
    boolean focusable = true;
    View popupView;
    LayoutInflater inflater, inflater2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                        getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
                width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                focusable = true;
                final PopupWindow popupwindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

                popupwindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        popupwindow.dismiss();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }

        });
       /* CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            maxISO = rangeISO.getUpper();
            minISO = rangeISO.getLower();
            rangeISO = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE);
            Range<Long> exposureTimeRange = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_EXPOSURE_TIME_RANGE);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ISORange = maxISO - minISO;
        ISO2 = minISO + (ISORange/5);
        ISO3 = minISO + (ISORange/5*2);
        ISO4 = minISO + (ISORange/5*3);
        ISO5 = minISO + (ISORange/5*4);
        isomin.setText(minISO);
        iso2.setText(ISO2);
        iso3.setText(ISO3);
        iso4.setText(ISO4);
        iso5.setText(ISO5);
        isomax.setText(maxISO);
*/
        ISOButton = findViewById(R.id.ISOButton);
        ISOButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                inflater2 = (LayoutInflater)
                        getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                popupView = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.isochanger, null);
                width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                Log.d("TAG",""+width);
                final PopupWindow popupwindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);
                popupwindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        popupwindow.dismiss();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Here is output screenshot.

[image]

Hope it may help you to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu  
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button);  
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());  

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener  
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                    return true;  
                }  
            });  

            popup.show();//showing popup menu  
        }  
    });//closing the setOnClickListener method
```